# Should I just use one reducer in redux for reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-reducers

I think if we have multiple reducer, it is just namespacing the state, right?

So if we don't need namespacing them, we could just use one reducer to store all the global state?

Comment: your question is opinion based, it's dependent on the features and the usecases that will be implemented in an app. using mutiple slices is a way of organising state in redux (each slice expose a reducer function), we often end up having multiple slices in a store, it's not compulsury but it's a good practice to have slices in your store. where you can at the top level combine reducers.